# Docker Image MariaDB

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mariadb

i want to create a docker image for a customer.
This image should contain everything so that the customer only has to start the image ...

I started from `ubuntu:22.10` and everything is working so far. 
**BUT** if i install the `mariadb-server` package to obviously use mariadb within the image i always get the error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'` - how can i fix that?

I already tried a view workarounds but non of that work ...

Comment: I had a similar issue with Docker and databases like Postgres and MySQL. It seems that your MariaDB server is either not running, or that you don't have permission to connect to it. When you install a database server, it doesn't start automatically. Can you adapt [this MySQL solution](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/error-2002-hy000-can-t-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock-2) to your case?

Comment: @NicholasObert thanks - found the same page, but that doesnt work for me :(

Comment: If you look what [mariadb](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/tree/master/10.8) does with their container, you'll see that packages with services aren't really designed for containers. Everything in a single container is the wrong model. Look at reusing the mariadb container (leverage existing work) and package it up with other containers in a compose file.

Comment: @danblack thanks - i transformed everything to work as an docker-compose config

Comment: Glad to hear, any mariadb container problems or feature requests do [let me know](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues).