# Mariadb service stops itself on docker

Tags: dockerfile, mariadb

I can build this Dockerfile normally, but when i run the container, the python
application crashes. After a while, I got into the container to debug and realized that happened because somehow the mariadb service was down, even after I turned it on in this line :`RUN service mariadb start && sleep 3 && \` . I already fixed this by creating another Dockerfile with different commands, but do someone know why the mariadb service suddently got down ?

```
FROM debian

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && apt install python3 python3-venv debconf-utils -y && \ 
    echo mariadb-server mysql-server/root_password password r00tp@ssw0rd | debconf-set-selections && \
    echo mariadb-server mysql-server/root_password_again password r00tp@ssw0rd | debconf-set-selections && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    mariadb-server \
    && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

RUN python3 -m venv venv

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN /app/venv/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash app

RUN chown app:app -R /app

RUN service mariadb start && sleep 3 && \
    mysql -uroot -pr00tp@ssw0rd -e "CREATE USER app@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'sup3r@ppp@ssw0rd';CREATE DATABASE my_lab_1; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_lab_1.* TO 'app'@'localhost';" && \
    mysql -uroot -pr00tp@ssw0rd -D "my_lab_1" < makedb.sql



EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/app/venv/bin/python3","/app/run.py"]
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908980/docker-image-mariadb#comment128826666_72908980).

Comment: `RUN` occurs at build time, not during the start of the container. There is no persistent services between run stages even at built time. Recommend using separate containers and the existing mariadb container along with compose to run two containers in the same pod.